# React state based on cookie not updating state of material ui switch on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I am using react cookie and able to successfully retrieve cookie:

```
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['darkTheme']);
  console.log("initial cookie is ",cookies.darkTheme) /// logs "true" as string
  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(Boolean(cookies.darkTheme));
  console.log("initial darkstate is  ", darkState) /// logs true as boolean as expected
```

Then in material ui switch, I try to use `darkState`

```
    {console.log("about to assign switch state as ", darkState)/// logs true}
    <Switch checked={darkState} onChange={handleThemeChange} name="darkSwitch" />
```

Here is the handlethemechange function although the problem is with the initial load even before the function is called.

```
  const handleThemeChange = () => {
    console.log("in theme change and darkState will be ", !darkState)
    darkState?setDarkState(false):setDarkState(true);
    setCookie('darkTheme', darkState, { path: '/' });
    console.log("in theme change cookie is  ", cookies.darkTheme)
  };
```

The above does not work and `checked={darkState}` always seems to be `false` although the console log just above it says its boolean value true.

If I just change `checked={darkState} to checked={true}`, the switch is checked and works but obviously, I do not want to just hard code true.

I am doing this in a child component so I cannot use getInitialProps option thats available in next js. I am trying to avoid using componentwillMount as I read on SO there are issues with it.

My guess is the cookie value although logs correctly in console, is not reaching the switch in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way next js pre renders everything so while things look good in the console logs, the form components do not get default value in time.

The solution is to use useEffect which can be used like componentDidMount.

In my case, I am putting the cookie value into the state of the switch so that it gets a state based on last set cookie value.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkState(cookies.darkTheme == "true");
  }, [darkState]);
```

Technically, this alone should solve the issue but I had to use a ref at the top of the component as well to make it work.

```
  const switched = useRef(cookies.darkTheme == "true"? true: false);
  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(switched);
```

I do not have an explanation for why I had to first assign the value to a ref and then put  it in useState. May be someone can suggest why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sfjkeq?file=src/App.js

If you try to line 10 to `const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(Boolean(!cookies.darkTheme));` it's changing the state of the Switch component.

Could you past more of your code in you post?

Comment: I posted the only other relevant code with is the handlechange when switch is clicked. Actually the link you provided shows `false` state all the time. In my case, I was getting it `true` in the console atleast.

Comment: I should add that the theme switching mechanism works but the only problem is the state of the switch on page refresh - its always checked=false

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my post, I've added the "!". In the code,  `useCookies(['darkTheme'])` returns `false` because we haven't set the cookie yet. If you  put `!cookies.darkTheme` on line 10, `darkState` will be true and it changes the Switch state

Comment: I see, but that defeats the purpose right? On page refresh, the switch will always be checked if I do that. What I am trying here is remembering what the user switched by getting value of the cookie upon page navigation or page refresh. You are right that if I use !, it will check the switch but it will be like hard coding it to true.

Comment: By using `!` I'm simulating the cookie set to `true`. What I want to show you is that with the bare minimum code it's working. Something else in you code is probably messing with the `darkState`

Comment: I dont think so because all my console logs were fine as expected. I think its the timing of render. Let me try and make sure I am not messing something.

Comment: I've updated the code and you can see that the Switch state can be changed by clicking on the button. Something else might be interfering with your state in your code

Comment: I agree the switch state changes with the button for me too. The only problem is when page is refreshed it goes back to `false` or when using ! goes back to `true` not matter what the cookie holds. If I just wanted to make this work without page refresh, I dont even need cookie and I could just use a state. Makes sense?

Comment: I found a solution which is to use useEffect. The answer you posted kills the last selected switch value on page refresh.